# Control fan and lights with IR and sensing if any human went or left the room

Tags: sensor, home-automation

I have a remote controlled light and a remote controlled fan. I want to automatically turn on the fan and light when a human comes into the room and turn off when a human leaves the room.

I need to know the distance of the passing object because I would have to come up with a logic to know whether the passing object is a human or just the door closing.

I see various sensors such as proximity sensors, infrared sensors, lasers but I'm not sure what to use.

Lastly, I would need IR receivers and emitters to record my remote control. I want to connect these sensors to my raspberry pi.

So what sensors should I use? And will I be able to plug these sensors to my raspberry PI (any need to get additional board such as arduino)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want a setup reacting instantly on entering/leaving a person (imagine someone sitting calmly for while)

So a [pir sensor](http://www.google.com/search?q=connecting+pir+sensor+to+raspberry+pi) which triggers with a hysteresis of minutes (like a staircase light) should suffice.

I'd suggest an [USB-IR-transceiver](http://www.irdroid.com/irdroid-usb-ir-transceiver/) controlled with LIRC for lights and fan.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a PIR sensor, they can be gotten for about $15.00 or more. The big box stores and others carry them. They come with different features so you can pick what you want. They will mount in the wall replacing the switch and are designed to operate on the mains power so no external circuits, boxes, etc needed. Here is a picture of one:
[image] This is not a recommendation for this particular $12.99 unit, just an indication of what they look like. There are many configurations. This will allow you to keep your Pi and do other projects.